# can we make a select picker over another in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a select picker with several options and I want to know if I it's possivel choose one option and pressing in that option open another  different select picker with different options.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for "I want to" questions and instead for "I've done X and I'm having problem Y" type questions.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score -1):

No, a multi-level select picker is not implementable that easily in pure HTML, at least I couln't think of a way to do that in a reasonable way.

What you can do is have multiple selects, and hide/show the secondary picker or change its options based on the selection of the first select. For this take a look at the [onChange Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp).

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/virhonestum/gjbhnrh2/21/) to help you better understand.
In this case the data is available in a multidimensional array, containing the subgroups for each option, as a tuple (value, text) like this:

```
var subOptions = [
  [
     [0, "Suboption 0.0"],
     [1, "Suboption 0.1"],
     [2, "Suboption 0.2"],
     [3, "Suboption 0.3"]
  ],[
     [0, "Suboption 1.0"],
     [1, "Suboption 1.1"]
  ],[
     [0, "Suboption 2.0"],
     [1, "Suboption 2.1"],
     [2, "Suboption 2.2"],
     [3, "Suboption 2.3"],
     [4, "Suboption 2.4"]
  ]
]
```

---

Edit:
While it is not that easy to implement in HTML, there are a few jQuery plugins available for this kind of thing, like [Flyout Menus](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery-ipod-style-and-flyout-menus.html) and [mcDropdown](https://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.cfm).

Comment: I have already made hidden text fields based on a yes or no question with javaScript, but I don't know how made multiple selects, where if I choose option A in the first select will show me Option X in the Second, if I choose otpion B in the first, will show option Y in the second, can u help me?

Comment: @DavidFerreira Take a look at the Fiddle I just added, maybe that wil help you understand how this works.